# Angular 2 routing removes big part of the original URL

Tags: angular

I have a small HTML page in a subfolder of my ASP.NET web application. The URL looks like this:

```
https://company.com/application/folder/index.html
```

When I load the page in any browser and the script bundle finishes loading, the URL changes to:

```
http://company.com/#/home
```

How could I preserve the original URL? I was expecting to see this:

```
https://company.com/application/folder/index.html#home
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `href` property in your `index.html` file.

```
<base href="/application/folder/">
```

But do know that all your files has to be relative to this path.

Hope this helps!!